# How to send object UserDto from login page to Dashboard Page on Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I worked on blazor server side . I need to pass object UserDto from login page to dashboard Page when success Login .

what I try as below

1-create class `UserDto`

```
public class UserDto
    {

        
        public string UserName { get; set; }

    
        public string Password { get; set; }
        
    }
```

2-on login component page (first page)  when success login I assign values of user name and password login to UserDto to values `username  and password`

```
 if (responseContent.ToString() == "Succed")
                        {

                            UserDto user = new UserDto();
                         user.UserName="michel"
                         user.Password="pass123"
                        }
```

3- on second page Dashboard `On Initialized` event

```
 public UserDto useres;
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        how to get value of username and password from
        UserDto
    }
```

so How to receive object from UserDto from login page on dashboard page ?

Comment: "Succed" is not a spelling I recognize.  If it's a misspelling, then the body of that block will be skipped.  But I have to ask-- why in the heck would you be permanently saving log-in information and passing it from page to page?

Comment: ok i changed but still object be null on second page although it fill applicationstate.userdto on first page

Comment: so what i do to solve issue can you please help me

Comment: Brother, no offense, but I don't even know what you are trying to do.

Comment: can you give me please alternative way to transfer object from one page to another page

Comment: You should use a Scoped service, and inject it into your page.  I think your original question did that, so you were close.

Comment: Done.  My answer is minimal working sample, but you can mark Farid's answer as the chosen answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DtoService.cs**

```
public class DtoService
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
        public string Pass { get; set; } = "";
    }
```

**Add this line in Program.cs after similar lines**

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<DtoService>();
```

**Index.razor**

```
@inject DtoServer DTS
@inject NavigationManager Nav

Name: <input @bind=IndexName />
Pass: <input @bind=IndexPass /><br />
<button @onclick=HandleClick>Go</button>
@code {
    public string IndexName;
    public string IndexPass;

    void HandleClick()
    {
        DTS.Name = IndexName;
        DTS.Pass = IndexPass;
        Nav.NavigateTo("/PageThatNeedsDto");
    }
}
```

**PageThatNeedsDto.razor**

```
@page "/PageThatNeedsDto"
@inject DtoServer DTS
@inject NavigationManager Nav

Name: @ReceivedName,
Pass: @ReceivedPass
<br />
<button @onclick=HandleClick>Back</button>
@code {
    public string ReceivedName;
    public string ReceivedPass;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ReceivedName = DTS.Name;
        ReceivedPass = DTS.Pass;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    void HandleClick()
    {
        Nav.NavigateTo("/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question why ApplicationStates.UserDto display null on second page
> although it correctly assigned on first page .

Actullay, while passing object from first page to second page you should initialize your ApplicationStates by injecting it as well which I cannot see on your first page this might be a main reason based on your shared code snippet.

In other words, you should inject ApplicationStates the same way what you are doing at your second page.

> Exactly I need to transfer object userdto from first page login to
> second page dashboard . Meaning transfer object have use name and
> password to second page dashboard

Well, let's a look on practice how we can pass userDTO using ApplicationStates class from first page to second page.

First Page:

```
@page "/FirstPage"
@using BlazorAppDemo.Models;
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject ApplicationStates appState
<PageTitle>FirstPage</PageTitle>



<PageTitle>FirstPage</PageTitle>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="PassObject">Pass Objct</button>

@code {



    private void PassObject()
    {
        appState.UserDto = new UserDto { UserName = "Kiron", Password = "123654", IsActive = true };
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/SecondPage");
       
    }
}
```

**Note:** The key point is `@inject ApplicationStates appState`. In addition to this,  I am using NavigationManager just redirecting to second page without that, object will pass to second page as well.

Second Page:

```
@page "/SecondPage"
@using BlazorAppDemo.Models;
@inject ApplicationStates appState

<PageTitle>SecondPage</PageTitle>

<h1>Object Received:@States.UserDto!.UserName </h1>
<h1>Object Received:@States.UserDto!.Password </h1>
<h1>Object Received:@States.UserDto!.IsActive </h1>

@code {
   

    public ApplicationStates States { get; set; }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        States = appState;

    }
}
```

Model:

[image]

Program.cs:

While I was writting this answer, I saw you have scoped service but later on you have omitted that from your question. However, in program.cs file you should have following AddScoped snippet:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ApplicationStates>();
```

[image]

**Note:**  As you have modified your question, so AddScoped should contain either your UserDto or previously shared class ApplicationStates.

Output:

[image]

**Note:** You could [check more details on our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: I'm pretty sure his original question actually had a Scoped service in it, but I couldn't understand what he was trying to achieve.

Comment: His requirement is clear, he wants `UserDto`  (which is property of ApplicationStates) from  one page to another. For instance, FirstPage to Second. He was using `AddScoped` correctly but missing `@inject ApplicationStates appState` in first page. As you know `@inject ApplicationStates appState` is required in both page if we want to pass object between. This would certainly resolve his null object.